# Need e.preventDefault to save JWT into localStorage

Tags: ajax, reactjs, forms, jwt

For some reason, when trying to login I need to have e.preventDefault (prevent page reloading) in order to save my JWT into local storage with an AJAX call. So when i have this:

```
handleLogin(e) {
//Without e.preventDefault, the jwt token is not save -> cannot access api
e.preventDefault();
const email = $('#email').val()
const password = $('#password').val()
const request = {"auth": {
  "email": email,
  "password": password
}}
$.ajax({
  url: "http://localhost:5000/api/user_token",
  type: "POST",
  data: request,
  dataType: "json",
  success: function (result){
    console.log(result.jwt)
    localStorage.setItem("jwt", result.jwt)
  }
})
}
```

Here is my simple form

```
render(){
return(
  <div>
    <form>
      <input
        name="email"
        id="email"
        type="email"
      />
      <input
        name="password"
        id="password"
        type="password"
      />
      <button
        onClick={this.handleLogin}
      >Login</button>
      <button
        onClick={this.handleLogout}
      >Logout</button>
    </form>
    <button onClick={this.getUsers}>Get Users</button>
    {
      this.state.users
    }
  </div>
)
}
```

I want my page to reload/go to a different page after submitting a successful login. On create-react-app and using a Rails API 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, you can try this:

```
success: function (result){
    console.log(result.jwt)
    localStorage.setItem("jwt", result.jwt)
    //page reload
    window.location.reload(true);
    // or route to another page
    window.location.href = 'foo'; // any route
  }
```

But I would recommend to use react router so your app will never loose it's state.
If you have any query, you can ask.

Comment: Thanks this does work when I leave e.preventDefault(). But I am confuse how the combination of e.preventDefault (prevents reload) but with the combination of windows.location saves the jwt? Why does that happen?

Comment: I guess I have found your issue. Change you handleLogin(e) {} with
handleLogin = (e)=> {}. And remove e.preventDefault(). It's binding issue of clickListener with DOM.